# store if loop results in a matrix (Octave)

Tags: sorting, if-statement, matrix, octave

I have a matrix with many random values ranging from -600 to +600. These values are intermixed with each other inside of the matrix.

What I want to do is separate the negative values and positive values into their own matrices. Maybe even separating the values that are greater than 400 into its own matrix as well.

I'm fairly new with coding, so the first thing that popped in my head was an if statement. I am using Octave. I don't know if theres a better way to go about it, but I would appreciate all help I can get. Thanks

Comment: you should try first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use logical indexing. You can create a logical matrix the size of your data based on the criteria you want.

So for example to get only the values that are negative:

```
negatives = your_data(your_data < 0);
```

And positive values

```
positives = your_data(your_data >= 0);
```

You can alter the expression used to generate the logical matrix to suit your needs.

Also if you're simply using Octave, you can stop tagging C++ since they are different languages.